# Draw Electrical Characteristics using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

How can i draw any one of the following transfer characteristics using tikz?
Especially arrows between the nodes?

[image: Characteristics]

Comment: Out of interest: What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: It is straightforward to draw arrows between nodes e.g. with `\draw[latex-latex] (node1) -- (node2) node[midway,fill=white] {$T_g$};`. What prevents me and possibly others from writing an answer is that it is tedious to redraw your diagram. So I'd like to ask you to show us what you've already done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left]{$v_{B1}$};
\draw (0,0) node[left]{0} -- (10,0) node[below left]{$t$};
\draw[very thick] (0,0.1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate (x1) -- ++(6,0)
coordinate (x2) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(2.5,0);
\draw[{Straight Barb[length=0pt,width=4mm] Latex[]}-{Latex[] Straight Barb[length=0pt,width=4mm]}] 
(1,0.5) -- (7,0.5) node[midway,fill=white]{$T_g$};
\node (VBE) at (0.5,1) {$V_{BE}$};
\draw[-{Latex[]}] (VBE)  -- (0.5,0.1);
\draw[-{Latex[]}] (0.5,-0.7) -- (0.5,-0.1);
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-8.5cm]
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[left]{$\ell_{C1}$};
\draw (0,0) node[left]{0} -- (10,0) node[below left]{$t$};
\draw[very thick] (0,1) node[left]{$\displaystyle\approx\frac{V_{CC}}{R}$} -- ++(1,0)
 -- ++(0,-1) coordinate (y1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,3) coordinate (y2) -- ++(1,0) --
 ++(0,-2) coordinate (y3) -- ++(1.5,0);
\node (ICBO) at (2,1) {$I_{CBO}\approx0$};
\draw[-{Latex[]}] (ICBO)  -- (2,0);
\draw[-{Latex[]}] (2,-0.7) -- (2,0);
\draw (5,3) -- (7,3);
\draw[{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (6,3) -- (6,0) node[midway,fill=white]{$\displaystyle
\frac{h_{FC}V_{CC}}{R_C}$};
\draw[thick] (11,3) -- (12,3) (11,1) -- (12,1);
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=5mm,post length=5mm,segment
length=5mm,amplitude=2.5mm}] (12,3) -- (12,1) node[midway,left=3pt] {$R_i$};
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-13cm]
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left]{$v_0$};
\draw (0,0) node[left]{0} -- (10,0) node[below left]{$t$};
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- ++(1,0)
coordinate (z1) -- ++(4,3) coordinate (z4) -- ++(2,0) coordinate (z2) -- ++(1,-3) 
coordinate (z3) -- ++(1.5,0);
\draw[{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (6,3) -- (6,0) node[midway,fill=white]{$V_{CC}$};
\draw (z1 |-0,0) -- ++ (0,-3) coordinate[pos=1/6] (l1) coordinate[pos=1/2] (l2)
coordinate[pos=5/6] (l3);
\draw (z3 |- 0,0) -- ++(0,-3) coordinate[pos=5/6] (r3);
\draw (z4 |- 0,0) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate[pos=1/2] (m1);
\draw (z2 |- 0,0) -- ++(0,-2) coordinate[pos=3/4] (m2);
\draw[{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (l1) -- (m1) node[midway,fill=white]{$T_*$};
\draw[{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (l2) -- (m2) node[midway,fill=white]{$T_g$};
\draw[{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (l3) -- (r3) node[midway,fill=white]{$T$};
\draw[dashed] (z4) -- (z4 |- 0,0);
\draw[dashed] (x2) -- (z2 |- 0,0);
\end{scope}
\draw[dashed] (x1) -- (z1) node[pos=0.1,fill=white] {$t=0$};
\draw[dashed] (y3) -- (z3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]